# Semantic Chunking with Langchain on FAISS vectorstore

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, chunking

I have this Langchain code for my own dataset:

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings

vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(
    docs, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()
```

and I want to add **semantic chunking** for the dataset (`docs`) before (or after if possible) I save them to the vector store. Specifically, I have been trying to add the following snippet before the previous code:

```
from langchain_experimental.text_splitter import SemanticChunker

text_splitter = SemanticChunker(OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY))
docs = text_splitter.create_documents(docs)
```

to convert `docs` into chunked format but it doesn't work possibly because the structure is different.

Has anyone tried and succeeded in this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
docs = text_splitter.create_documents([docs])
```

which expects a `[list]`. Reference > https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_transformers/semantic-chunker